# Read all the text files in a folder and change a character in a string if it presents

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a folder with csv formated documents with a .arw extension. Files are named as `1.arw, 2.arw, 3.arw` ... etc.

I would like to write a code that reads all the files, checks and replaces the forwardslash `/` with a dash `-`. And finally creates new files with the replaced character.

The code I wrote as follows:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    my_file=open("/path/"+str(i)+".arw", "r+")
    str=my_file.read()

    if "/" not in str:
        print("There is no forwardslash")
    else:
        str_new = str.replace("/","-")
        print(str_new)

        f = open("/path/new"+str(i)+".arw", "w")
        f.write(str_new)
        my_file.close()
```

But I get an error saying:

> 'str' object is not callable.

How can I make it work for all the files in a folder? Apparently my for loop does not work.

Comment: You should not use `str` as a variable name, since python already uses it.

Comment: Any reason you prefer `Python` here instead of `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Your code has obvious syntax errors, could you please [edit] to fix the indentation?

Comment: @lagom Your edit is obviously well-intentioned, but second-guessing the OP's actual code is something we try to avoid. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348957/why-did-this-non-compiling-code-edit-got-rejected

Comment: @tripleee I agree sometimes, the indent itself maybe the root cause of the question. But here, I did not see the root cause is the indent, it seems just the op not familiar with the markdown, what's your opinion?

Comment: My guess would be similar to yours, but again, we are not really supposed to be guessing these things. Eventually close as unclear if the OP is unable to post exactly the actual code they are having problems with.

Comment: @tripleee Maybe you are correct, I just see so many indent edit in python post approved, make me think this is a correct thing we could do...  @ op, you can revert my changes if needed.

Comment: I actually wrote the code for a single file and it was working. The indentions are somewhat changed after I copy paste here. Sorry for not checking them after c/p. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: no I don't have any specific reason to do it with python. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is that you are replacing the built-in `str` with your own variable with the same name, then try to use the built-in `str()` after that.

Simply renaming the variable fixes the immediate problem, but you really want to refactor the code to avoid reading the entire file into memory.

```
import logging
import os

for i in range(1,6):
    seen_slash = False
    input_filename = "/path/"+str(i)+".arw"
    output_filename = "/path/new"+str(i)+".arw"
    with open(input_filename, "r+") as input, open(output_filename, "w") as output:
        for line in input:    
           if not seen_slash and "/" in line:
               seen_slash = True
            line_new = line.replace("/","-")
            print(line_new.rstrip('\n')) # don't duplicate newline
            output.write(line_new)
    if not seen_slash:
        logging.warn("{0}: No slash found".format(input_filename))
        os.unlink(output_filename)
```

Using `logging` instead of `print` for error messages helps because you keep standard output (the `print` output) separate from the diagnostics (the `logging` output).  Notice also how the diagnostic message includes the name of the file we found the problem in.

Going back and deleting the output filename when you have examined the entire input file and not found any slashes is a mild wart, but should typically be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    with open((str(i)+'.arw'), 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()

        for element in data:
            element.replace('/', '-')
        f.close()
    with open((str(i)+'.arw'), 'w') as f:
        for element in data:
            f.write(element)
        f.close()
```

this is assuming from your post that you know that you have 6 files

if you don't know how many files you have you can use the OS module to find the files in the directory.

Comment: Reading the data into a list and iterating over that list is inefficient because *(a)* you effectively loop over it twice, and *(b)* if the file is big, you use a lot of memory.

Comment: it is an effective and easily understandable solution to the problem, as well as this,  the str.replace() method is effectively the same. I am also assuming that as he is doing this his files are not too big. Thanks for the feedback though

Comment: The file contents are not huge. So this works ok as well. But the strategy suggested by @triplee below is even better just in case the content is big.